# How to set default python interpreter in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, interpreter

Every-time i start Pycharm i need to tell it what is my default interpreter. But it forgets and asks against after restarting the program. Is there anyway i can set it so that PyCharm would remember what my default interpreters was so I don't need to specify it when i restart the software?

Comment: Specify the default project interpreter in the settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you can set it.
[image]

Here you can set interpreter for every upcoming project.

In previous versions it was like.

```
File->Default Settings
```