# Changing Python Interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python, interpreter

I have been using the 3.8.6 version of Python. I wanted to change to 3.9. I went to the official website
and have downloaded it. But, I can't change my Interpreter in the IDE I use(PyCharm). Please help.

Thanks

PS: I am new to programming and don't know much. Please be easy.

Comment: Just go to `File>settings>Project` ..You will see the option of changing the interpreter if you have more than one.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter

Comment: @AbrarAhmed I don't see anything in the settings named as project. I see a tab named python interpreter. When I click on it it says, 'nothing to show in here.' Thanks for the help.

Comment: this may [help add python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html)

Comment: You need to set the new python in your system PATH. I think you might not have done that. You don't see project, because you have no projects. Please set the python PATH then you will see the option.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767672/how-to-set-default-python-interpreter-in-pycharm/58768171#58768171

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help! Appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

Open a new file and it automatically will ask u to select the existing interpreters and it will show the location of each while choosing ex. Virtualenv, pipenv, conda etc

Comment: Please, clarify your answer. Explain it more.